# Java: Quit Callable instance in an Executor wrapped under CompletionService

Tags: java, java-stream, executorservice, callable

I have got a Connector class that establishes the connection and delegates tasks to two subtasks - JobManager and DataRetriever. I used observer pattern with JobManager as Observable. This submits an entry pair to the Connector class.

A typical connector class looks like:

```
    class Connector implements Observable, Closeable
    {
    ....
    private void submitandMonitor(List<Callable<String>> bulkTasks, List<Callable<String>> soapTasks)
            throws InterruptedException
    {

        // Bulk job submission
        bulkExecutor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(NBULKTHREADS,
                new ThreadFactoryBuilder().setNameFormat("BulkDownloader-%d").build());
        bulkCompletionService = new ExecutorCompletionService<String>(bulkExecutor);
        bulkTasks.forEach(task -> bulkCompletionService.submit(task));

        // Status poll thread configuration
        statusPollExec = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(0,
                new ThreadFactoryBuilder().setNameFormat("StatusPoller").build());
        statusPollExec.scheduleAtFixedRate(statusPoller, 15, 15, TimeUnit.MINUTES);

        // Wait until all the bulk jobs are completed
        shutdownLatch.await();
        bulkExecutor.shutdown();

    }


    @Override
    public void close() throws SQLException, ClientProtocolException, IOException,
            RetriesExhaustedException
    {
        try
        {
            if (bulkExecutor != null)
            {
                if (!bulkExecutor.isShutdown())
                    bulkExecutor.shutdown();
                bulkExecutor.awaitTermination(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                logger.debug("Bulk executor shutdown completed");
            }
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e)
        {
            logger.warn("Auto shutdown duration exceeded, manually terminating Bulk executor!");
            bulkExecutor.shutdownNow();
            logger.warn("Manual shutdown for Bulk executor completed");
        }
....// Same set of try catches for executors


    }

    }
```

The job manager consists of:

```
 class JobManager
    {

// Method that does not bother about thread shutdown
private void submitJobs()
{
    // Had sObjects.parallelStream() but changed to an iterative loop suspecting not responding to shutdown - Probably the offending method
    for(Entry<SalesforceObject, Boolean> item : sObjects.entrySet())
    {
        SalesforceObject sObject = item.getKey();
        Boolean queryAll = item.getValue();
        try
        {
            // Method to submit the values for bulk requests. No loop
            submitBulkJob(sObject, queryAll);
            // Add to jobDetailMap <,> when job successful; used in monitorJobs()
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            // Set the params and send info to observer
        }
    }
}

private void monitorJobs() throws InterruptedException
{
    while (jobdetailMap.size() > 0)
    {
        for (Iterator<Entry<SalesforceObject, JobDetail>> iterator = jobdetailMap.entrySet().iterator(); iterator
                .hasNext();)
        {
            Entry<SalesforceObject, JobDetail> entry = iterator.next();
            SalesforceObject sObject = entry.getKey();
            String sObjname = sObject.getsObjname();
            // Check for status and send info to observer
        }
        Thread.sleep(Constants.sleep5000);
    }
}

    @Override
        public String call() throws Exception
        {
            submitJobs();
            monitorJobs();
            setsObjectstatus(null);
            return this.getClass().getSimpleName();
        }
    }
```

`submitJobs()` is the one that submits on iterating through tasklist and submitting. `monitorJobs()` iterates and checks for the status of the tasklist and does not terminate until it is complete.

Since close already closes and terminates this, I noticed that the job manager still notifies the connector and I frequently end up with TaskRejectedExecution. Does this imply that the `shutDownNow()` does not terminate the instance? Follow up: another question that arises is that if I use a parallel stream to submit the jobs in Job manager, and if the thread terminates, how should I handle ending the parallel stream?

Comment: You're more likely to get answers to this if you can isolate the problem a bit more.  The length of the code you've included is daunting.  :)  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @BPS My apologies. Cleaned up and added comments. Hope this makes the code clearer to understand.

Comment: Try to use Fork/Join Framework https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/forkjoin.html I think it's more appropriate in your case.